# /help/whats-meta should link to meta.site[.stackexchange].com/search, not to site[.stackexchange].com/search

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, help-center

On [I suppose] all sites' /help/whats-meta (but Meta.SE's):

> Please *look around* to see if your question has been asked before, and avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with [site] or the Stack Exchange network. This is not a random discussion area; rather, it's a place for improving our community and website, together.

*Look around* links to `site[.stackexchange].com/search`.

But I gather I should be searching on `meta.site[.stackexchange].com/search`  before asking a question on `meta.site[.stackexchange].com`?

Because that would explain the frequent Déjà-vus.

[Sample /help/whats-meta on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that would make a lot of sense. I've updated the help articles accordingly.